# Can I install RubyMine 5 with openJDK instead of Oracle JDK?

Tags: linux, ide, rubymine, java

I already have openJDK installed on my system (Fedora 19), and I'd rather not put the Oracle JDK on it. Is it possible to run RubyMine 5 with openJDK instead? If yes, how. If no, then why? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. However, there are some issues. When you install RubyMine, you are warned about those. For example, resizing or clicking away popup interface components is somewhat problematic and doesn't work as expected. I'd say minor glitches.